# Suppress a field and its placeholder in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, suppression

I am working in Crystal Reports to generate a report, and I would like to add a note/remark for some records, so the record should be double-lined for these specific records and a single-line for others

the issue is that the row should be in its standard height unless a specific field has a certain value. In that case, the row should be expanded and field with red-colored note is placed in the expansion.

I tried suppressing the fields but it does not remove the placeholder

The attached is what I am aiming to do, the Zurich Record has a note in red color, announcing the trip is for ladies only.
[image]

I will be gratefull for anyone can give me a hand

Comment: So you wish to hide *Ladies only and based on condition it should show? Can you confirm?

Comment: Yes.. Confirmed.. In addition to shrink/expand the row accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to accomplish the same.

1. Create a name field formula and append the "conditional text" based on logic

   ```
   if condition then 
   text:=text + "*dummy text"; // this is just an example

   //add conditional color logic for appended text
   ```
2. Create another detail section just below the existing detail, and add conditional show hide logic to suppress.

   You have to check the alignment of fields in the previous detail section for "Can Grow" option- like you want "dummy text" to be aligned in height with other column data?. Because with this option, your text field will always appear to be below your row.
3. You can add another field and place it below Name, and add formula on its height to be suppressed, based on condition. (Again this will mess up if your name field grows into multiple lines, by overlapping this field in the process).

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with a second `DetailSection`.

- Create a new `DetailSection` below the existing one.
- Put the note/remark in the new `DetailSection`
- Edit the suppression-formula of the new `DetailSection` and insert the suppression-formula that's currently used on the note/remark-field